# Using NuGet in an automated build and branched environment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, nuget

We’re on a closed network without Internet access so we’re currently using a file share as a NuGet repository.  We do a lot of merging between a development branch and a main branch and occasionally setup a one-off branch for a hotfix or large functionality that will extend beyond our normal release cycles.

What we’ve found is that when we add a NuGet package to a project it puts a file path in the .csproj file for where the package is located.  This works fine until we merge into another branch in TFS and then kick off a build.  The builds do not pull down the same files from source control (keeping dev and main completely separate in that regards) so the package path is not found and the build fails.

We’ve come up with one solution we know will work but is utterly painful and one proposed solution that we need to investigate further.  One solution is to put the packages folder into a common location that every build will include in its workspace and manually modify each .csproj file to point to that location for its packages.

The solution we need to investigate is [using NuGet without committing packages to source control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).  What we need to determine is if NuGet.exe will create the folder structure needed by the .csproj file to find the package.

Are there better solutions to using NuGet in a branching environment that uses automated builds?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a *local* NuGet repository that is reachable by http:// that can be easily used in both branch situations. Checkout how to create a local NuGet repository [here](http://rizamarhaban.ecodevsys.com/20111125/walkthrough-creating-nuget-local-server-private-repository/)